# AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies fails with ReflectionTypeLoadException

Tags: c#, reflection

During unittesting I have run into a problem with the following code that asks for all the loaded assemblies:

```
var res = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
.SelectMany(x => x.GetTypes())
.ToList();
```

this code fails with a ReflectionTypeLoadException which has inner exceptions of the pattern

> Could not load type Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.FOO

where `FOO` are some specific classes also coded by us.

The problem arises when running unittests prior to the above which creates XML documents using the XDocument class.

I may not necesarilly want to load these code generated classes (I'm guessing Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.* is code generated.) I just want to understand whats wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should check IsDynamic field of your assembly which is availabe at .netframework 4 and later.

```
var res = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().Where(ass => ass.IsDynamic == false)
.SelectMany(x => x.GetTypes())
.ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you turn on Fusion log to see why are the Assemblies failing to load?

[How to enable assembly bind failure logging (Fusion) in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/255669/how-to-enable-assembly-bind-failure-logging-fusion-in-net)

Comment: I was not able to find out anything

Answer (score 0):

I ended up concluding that the classes that are run-time code generated for serialization and xmlserialization (and others?) are uninterestingto me. Thus the following filter helped

```
return AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
.Where(x => !x.FullName.StartsWith("Microsoft.GeneratedCode"))
.SelectMany(x => x.GetTypes())
.ToList();
```