# Assembly "Microsoft.GeneratedCode" loaded

Tags: c#, .net, .net-assembly

My application reports that it has loaded an assembly called "Microsoft.GeneratedCode". I would like to verify, which part of my applications or assemblies behind, are generating this specific assembly. The assembly is loaded only once.

Details about the loaded assembly:

- IsDynamic = true
- Name = Microsoft.GeneratedCode
- Version = 1.0.0.0 Culture = neutral
- PublicKeyToken = null
- ImageRuntimeVersion = "v4.0.30319"

In general, my application connects to an Apache ActiveMQ by using the Apache.NMS 1.7.0.3635, Apache.NMS.ActiveMQ 1.7.0.3660 and on the other side my app deals with HTTPS request/responses containing serialized models (XML).

During my research I found the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19044388/4362911), which indicates that the assembly "Microsoft.GeneratedCode" is related to XML serialization.

Comment: It is a system assembly that probably is needed by some of your referenced assemblies. Why is this important?

Comment: @atornblad I need to verify, why this assembly is loaded and I would like to learn more about environemt behind.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could register for the event [`AppDomain.AssemblyLoad`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.appdomain.assemblyload) and then get a stack trace from within the event handler (putting a breakpoint in the handler and using the debugger would probably be the easiest way to get the stack trace).

Although based on your research you will probably find that XML Serialization has created a dynamic assembly. There were a lot of hits when I googled for:

> xml serialization dynamically loaded assembly

Comment: I can confirm that the xml serialization dynamically loads the assembly "Microsoft.GeneratedCode".

Comment: Does that answer your question?